# Knockout.js composable components?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am thinking of using Knockout.js to create reusable components. However, by reading the docs, I don't know how would I implement a component that can hold other (potentially different with each use) components inside it.

For example, I would like to implement a side-menu-view component, which would contain a title bar with menu button, a menu panel, and a content panel. The contents of the menu and content panels should not be defined in advance. For example, in one use case I would put a list-view component into the menu panel, in another use case I could put a list of checkboxes into the menu panel.

As what I understand from the docs, in Knockout.js the template of a component must be defined fully, and does not offer places where other components could be inserted later. Or am I wrong? Can it be done? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I want to create a component , which could be used as:

```
<side-menu-view>
  <menu>
    <!-- I can put anything here -->
  </menu>
  <content>
    <!-- I can put anything here -->
  </content>
</side-menu-view>
```

I understand the child nodes of a component can be accessed via $componentTemplateNodes, but then I want to be able to get the contents of `<menu>` and `<content>` separately, and put it within the appropriate places of my component layout.

**UPDATE 2:**

Example use:

```
<side-menu-view>
  <menu>
    This is a menu!
  </menu>
  <content>
    This is content!
  </content>
</side-menu-view>
```

Or like this:

```
<side-menu-view>
  <menu>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
  <content>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </content>
</side-menu-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the custom html element syntax, then you're right, you have to know the components when you write your html, like so:

```
<menu-panel>
    <list params="..."/>
</menu-panel>
```

However, you have the [component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) which lets you choose the component at run time:

```
<menu-panel>
    <div data-bind="component: {
        name: yourDynamicComponentName,
        params: { ... },
    }"/>
</menu-panel>
```

Note, of course, that `yourDynamicComponentName` must still be registered so knockout knows where to find it.

RE: Update 2 (focusing only on the `menu` control as it's obviously similar for the `content` control):

So you just define two components, one called `menu-list` and one called `menu-static`:

```
// html for a component called "menu-list"
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>

// html for a component called "menu-static"
This is a menu!
```

And in your `viewModel` for `side-menu-view` you can have a property called `menuType`, and you would use it in the html for `side-menu-view` like this:

```
// html for "side-menu-view"
<div data-bind="component: { name: menuType }"/>
```

So now you can set `menuType('menu-static')` or `menuType('menu-list')` when you want to toggle between menu types.

Comment: Could I use the following? `<menu-panel> <!-- ko component: #SOMETHING HERE?# --><!-- /ko --></menu-panel>`

Comment: Additionally, with this approach I would not be able to put a simple `<h1>Ha ha ha</h1>` into the content area, because `<h1>` is not a registered component.

Comment: `h1` is just a standard html element, knockout doesn't touch those at all, so there's no problem there.  As far as using the component binding in a comment, you can try it in a fiddle but if it's not supported you can always write your own comment-block compatible custom binding.

Comment: thanks for your replies. If you can tell me how to do the things I described in `UPDATE 2` in the question, I will accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, I don't want to spell everything out because I'd hate for you to just copy paste this into your work and not understand it.  It's rewarding to understand how this stuff works, it'll help you answer your own questions in the future.

Comment: Hi, thanks! What you say works, I accepted the answer. It would be nice though if I didn't have to define a separate component for any type I want to use withing the side-menu-view. Let me know if you come up with a better idea, but this would work for now :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

A knockout's model can be "pre-defined" for common usage and then extended for particular purpose. This means:

1. create an object/model as you'd do normally
2. create an object/model which has the extended properties
3. mix the two models with, i.e., jQuery's $.extend

Example:

```
var mainModel = function () {
    this.blablabla = ko.observable('blablabla');
}

var extendedModel = function () {
    this.sup = ko.observable('sup');
}

var myModelInstance = $.extend({}, new mainModel(), new extendedModel());

console.log(myModelInstance.blablabla(), myModelInstance.sup()); // "blablabla", "sup"
```

Comment: Hi Jack, but this doesn't answer my question about composite components... Is think something like componentTemplateNodes will be needed, not sure

Comment: Actually components are nothing more than objects that include a viewModel and a template. IMO though the best thing to do is to separate the template logics from the MVVM framework as you're writing HTML inside of JS (see: handlebars). That said, you can quickly extend in the same way different component *definitions* and register different components just calling the extend to mix the "main" and the "extender" - edit - or try out web components :) http://webcomponents.org/